# Can't load Handlebars with require config path and shim

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I've loaded handlebars with bower so it resides in a vendor directory. It seems I've configured everything to the point where I can see in inspector that the handlebars.js file is loaded, it doesn't give a 404.. but as far as I know the following should affix it to the global namespace (window). As you can see I have my module "loaded" and that works correct, but inside that module it depends upon handlebars - `ReferenceError: Handlebars is not defined`

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "/scripts",
    urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime(),
    paths: {
        "jquery": "vendor/jquery/dist/jquery",
        "loaded": "vendor/loaded/dist/loaded",
        "handlebars": "vendor/handlebars/handlebars"
    },
    shim: {
        "loaded": {
            deps: ["jquery", "handlebars"],
            exports: "loaded"
        },
        "handlebars": {
            exports: "Handlebars"
        }
    }
});

requirejs(["app"]);
```

Here is a snippet of the loaded module (non-AMD, loads with shim config):

```
if(typeof loaded === "undefined") loaded = {};

loaded.dispatch = (function() {

    // ...

    return {
        render: function () {

            // ...

            // gets this far, but error as the library is missing
            var template = Handlebars.compile(_template);

            // ...
        }
    }
})();
```

As mentioned, I can see in the inspector that Handlebars is NOT a property of the global namespace (window). From other posts I've read, I can't see what I've configured wrong. Also, as loaded is being required, I'm not sure what the issue is with handlebars.

UPDATE

New main.js as handlebars version doesn't require it, it would seem:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "/scripts",
    urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime(),
    paths: {
        "jquery": "vendor/jquery/dist/jquery",
        "loaded": "vendor/loaded/dist/loaded",
        "handlebars": "vendor/handlebars/handlebars"
    },
    shim: {
        "loaded": {
            deps: ["jquery", "handlebars"],
            exports: "loaded"
        }
    }
});

requirejs(["app"]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need (and should not) shim `handlebars` as the library integrates a [UMD wrapper](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) and thus, is compatible with the [AMD pattern](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/blob/master/AMD.md) (of which `requirejs` is an implementation):

```
if(typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module === 'object')
    module.exports = factory();
else if(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)
    define([], factory);
else if(typeof exports === 'object')
    exports["Handlebars"] = factory();
else
    root["Handlebars"] = factory();
```

And actually, because when the library will load it will find the `define` function, it won't append `Handlebars` to the root object (which is `window`).
As a result, obviously, your shim can't find it.

Now your problem is that you want to use Handlebars, an AMD loaded module, with a non AMD module. Unfortunately, this is not officially supported:

> Only use other "shim" modules as dependencies for shimmed scripts, or AMD libraries that have no dependencies and call define() after they also create a global (like jQuery or lodash). Otherwise, if you use an AMD module as a dependency for a shim config module, after a build, that AMD module may not be evaluated until after the shimmed code in the build executes, and an error will occur. The ultimate fix is to upgrade all the shimmed code to have optional AMD define() calls.

There is no good solutions. Here are some ideas:

**(1)** I still managed to make it works by creating a `globalHandlebars` module with:

```
define(["handlebars"], function(Handlebars){
    window.Handlebars = Handlebars;
});
```

But this is very hacky and not officially supported. Indeed, it seems that you are not guaranteed that the dep's `define` will be called before your non AMD script is loaded. Never happened on my laptop though...

**(2)** Another way to make it works is to include `handlebars` as a script in your html file **before** `requirejs` (so that `define` is not yet defined).
Still very hacky and if you also use handlebars with `requirejs`, it will be loaded twice...

**(3)** Obviously the best would be if you could wrap your `loaded` script in a `define` call but I guess it may not be possible.

**(4)** If you use the optimiser, there is also a [`wrapShim`](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/b8a6982d2923ae8389355edaa50d2b7f8065a01a/build/example.build.js#L68) option though it does not always work depending on the content of your shimmed code.

I don't have any other solutions but maybe the `requirejs` people have one. I am surprised nobody stumbled on this issue before you.

You may also consider switching to [browserify](http://browserify.org) or [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/docs/) instead of requirejs (webpack natively supports AMD modules and there is an [AMD loader](https://github.com/jaredhanson/deamdify) for browserify).
Additionally, both of them enables you to pre-build your templates (using [this loader](https://github.com/altano/handlebars-loader) for webpack or this [transform](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify-handlebars) for browserify) and avoid including the whole `handlebars` library which is always a good practice.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've got handlebars v4.0.4 and I can see in the file that it does indeed have the `if .. else if .. else` condition you posted. I matched the config you provided (removed the handlebars shim) but still I get the same error. I would appear that main.js (file with the configs) is not being cached either. So, if handlebars isn't being appended to the window object, do you know where in the DOM I should find it? I tried searching in the DOM inspector but it didn't bring up any results. Or is there anything else I can look at? I'll update my OP with new main.js. Thanks again.

Comment: It is probably not be appended in the global context at all (a variable is never appended to the dom, dom is for nodes, e.g. div, not variables). With requirejs, you retrieve a module as argument of the define function: `define(["handlebars"], function(Handlebars){ /* stuff */ }`. I do not currently have a computer but I'll have a closer look later.

Comment: I edited my answer. Unfortunately, this is far from perfect but I don't think you can do much better.

Comment: Actually, I took your code you copied from Handlebars (optional AMD define) and tweaked it for my loaded library. This way, I don't have to shim the loaded library either as handlebars is a dependency in the proper way. And, I guess with the handlebars set as a module too, now nothing is being amended to the global namespace. I guess that is the preferred approach, maybe what I was trying to do it for third-party libraries that simply do not support define calls. Anyway, it was really helpful your post as I'm still new to requirejs and trying to learn best practices. Thanks again.